# making pagination for out-put form

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to know how to make a pagination on an out-put form, the out-put form is the form that been answered by user.

I am using Wordpress but I need to hardcode it so the sql that you see, are for post-type, in Wordpress.

Here is the code:

```
 <?php
//echo $current_user->user_email;

        $sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type="special_occasions" AND post_title = "' . $useremail . '" AND post_status = "publish"';
        $results2 = $wpdb->get_results($sql2);

       // print_r($results2);

            if ($results2) { 
                foreach($results2 as $post2){
                    $post_id2 = $post2->ID;
                    $special_msg = get_post_meta($post_id2);
                    ?>

                    <!-- <ul class="one-time">
                    <li> -->

                    <div class="special_message" data-id="<?php echo $post_id2?>" style="" >

                    
                   
                        <form method="POST" name="frmArchive_<?php echo $post_id2?>" id=="frmArchive_<?php echo $post_id2?>">
                    
                        <div class="archive-form-group col-md-12">
                        <label for="txtMessage_<?php echo $post_id2?>" class="form-label"><h4 class="form-group-title">Message</h4></label>
                        <textarea class="form-control txtMessage readonly" id="txtMessage_<?php echo $post_id2?>" name="txtMessage" rows="3"><?php echo $special_msg['message'][0];?></textarea>
                        </div>


                        <div class="archive-form-group col-md-12">             
                            <label for="txtDedicatedTo_<?php echo $post_id2?>"><h4 class="form-group-title">Dedicated to</h4></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control txtDedicatedTo readonly" id="txtDedicatedTo_<?php echo $post_id2?>" name="txtDedicatedTo" aria-describedby="DedicatedToHelp" value="<?php echo $special_msg['dedicated_to'][0];?>" placeholder="Please enter name of recipient">

                            <!--<small id="DedicatedToHelp" class="form-text text-muted">To whom this message is dedicated to</small>-->

                        </div>     


                        <div class="archive-form-group col-md-12">             
                            <label for="txtRelationship_<?php echo $post_id2?>"><h4 class="form-group-title">Relationship</h4></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control txtRelationship readonly" id="txtRelationship_<?php echo $post_id2?>" name="txtRelationship" value="<?php echo $special_msg['relationship'][0];?>"  aria-describedby="RelationshipHelp" placeholder=" Relationship i.e. 'Father', 'Mother',...">

                            <!--<small id="RelationshipHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Your relationship to the recipient of this message</small>-->

                        </div>


                        <div class="archive-form-group col-md-12">             
                            <label for="txtType_<?php echo $post_id2?>"><h4 class="form-group-title">Type</h4></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control txtType readonly" id="txtType_<?php echo $post_id2?>" name="txtType" aria-describedby="TypeHelp" placeholder="Enter type" value="<?php echo $special_msg['type'][0];?>">

                            <!--<small id="TypeHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Type</small>-->

                        </div> 


                        <div class="archive-form-group col-md-12">             
                            <label for="txtoccas_<?php echo $post_id2?>"><h4 class="form-group-title">Occasions</h4></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control txtoccas readonly" id="txtoccas_<?php echo $post_id2?>" name="txtoccas" aria-describedby="occasHelp" placeholder="Enter Occasions" value="<?php echo $special_msg['occas'][0];?>">

                            <!--<small id="TypeHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Type</small>-->

                        </div>   
                        <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $post_id2?>" />
                        <input type="hidden"  name="action" value="update" />
                                </form> 


                        <div class="container" style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;justify-content: flex-start; align-items: center;margin-top:20px;">                               
                            <button   class="btn btn-warning btnEditMsg" style="max-width:25%;margin-right:350px">Edit Message</button> 
                            <button name="update"  type="submit" form="frmArchive_<?php echo $post_id2?>" class="btn btn-warning btnSaveMsg" style="max-width:25%;margin-right:50px;display:none;">Save Message</button> 
                            <button  class="btn btn-warning btnCancel" style="max-width:25%;display:none;margin-right:250px">Cancel</button>
                        </div>                                                   
                             
                        
                    </div>
                <!-- </li>
                    </ul> -->

                    <?php
                }
            }
?>
</div>

</section>
</div>
</div>
```